# Display time Format

Tags: android, time

From a Web Service, I display a list with time. I want to display time like this example "12:56"

This is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < time.length(); i++)
{
  JSONObject list_time = tab.getJSONObject(i);

  String time_str = list_time.getString("time-string");

 // Convert String to Date
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 Date time_to_time = df.parse(time_str);

 myList.add(new Model(id, time_to_time));

}
```

But I got this :

```
Thu Jan 01 12:56:00 UTC+01:00 1970
```

I want just to display 12:56, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because you are parsing it into a `Date` object, parse it into `String`. You can use this:

```
public String getFormatedStringTime(Date date)
{ 
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");  
    return df.format(date);
}
```